# Webdriver Inline Editing : How to handle mouse over and double click

Tags: hyperlink, webdriver, inline-editing

I need to double-click for inline editing. I am facing issue if the object is already populated and is a hyperlink. The moment i use double-click, the link opens, instead of field in edit mode.
Here is the HTML code

```
<td class="dataCol ">
<span id="cust_contact"> 
<span ondblclick="if (window.sfPage && window.sfPage.hasRun) 
sfPage.dblClickField(event,this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfPage && window.sfPage.hasRun) sfPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfPage && window.sfPage.hasRun) sfPage.clickField(event, this);" onmouseover="if (window.sfPage && window.sfPage.hasRun) sfPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" class="inlineEditWrite" style="display:block" id="cust_contact_ilecell">
<span id="cust_contact_ileinner">
<a href="https://XXXXXXXX" id="lookup003" onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup003').hide();" onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup003', '/003/m?retURL=%2Fapr%2FForceOrderInLineEditPage%3Fid%3Da1bWzo%26sf.override%3D1&amp;isAjaxRequest=1&amp;nocache=1344333834626').show();" onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup003').hide();" onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup003', '/003/m?retURL=%2Fapr%2FForceOrderInLineEditPage%3Fid%3Da1bWzo%26sf.override%3D1&amp;isAjaxRequest=1&amp;nocache=1344333834626').show();">
Joey Tribbiani</a>
</span></span></span></td>
```

On mouseover it display an image which can be used to click. But I am unable to find locator for the same, as it is tied to the 'class'.

Thanks

Comment: I'll think you have to use [AdvancedUserInteractions](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions). First use [MoveMouseAction](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/MoveMouseAction.html) and then [DoubleClickAction](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/DoubleClickAction.html)

Comment: @VolkerK - I did mouse over action, but then for double-click the locator is same, so it clicks in middle of the element,  which opened the hyperlink. I don't know how to click on the image which shows up on mouse over action.